# OSX custom keyboard field

Tags: objective-c, macos, unity-game-engine

I am creating an application using Unity3d platform, and I want to show native osx textfields for my osx build.

Is there way to show native text field?

I have tried to add textField to NSWindow, but it is not visible.

```
NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 100)];
[textField setStringValue:@"VALUE"];

NSApplication * shAp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
NSWindow *window = [shAp windows][1];

if (window != NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"window found, add subview");
    [[window contentView] addSubview:textField];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this is using child window.

I create Child Window and then add TextField as subview.
All works fine, but I should resize child window when parent window is resizing.

```
 NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 50)];
 NSApplication * shAp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
 NSWindow *window = [shAp windows][1];

 NSWindow *overlayWindow = [[NSWindow alloc]initWithContentRect:newRect
                                                         styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                           backing:window.backingType
                                                             defer:NO];

 [window addChildWindow:overlayWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
 [[overlayWindow contentView] addSubview:textView];
```